# how do i make a button proc in assembly 8086?

Tags: assembly, button, mouse, dos, x86-16

i am making a game in assembly for a project i have in school and i want to make a "start" button, when you click on it, the game starts. if someone has tips or all ready written code on how to make the function i would really appreciate it! thank you... i am working with DOS and 8086 so please in this format...

```
start_button dw 'Start','$'
```

when the function finishes, i dont want it to `jmp` anywhere i just want the function to end and the program will keep going on its own.

I am doing it in bitmap mode and I would like to loop and wait for a mouse click until the user hits the button with his mouse, after that the game will start.

Comment: click on it with a mouse instead of a keyboard?  How are you getting mouse input?  Is the screen going to be in text mode or bitmap graphics mode?  Are there any other buttons, or do you just want to call this function and have it keep looping until the user clicks in the right place?  So it's equivalent to a wait-for-keypress but for a mouse?

Comment: @PeterCordes I suppose `int 33h` might be a reasonable assumption.  OP could also mean the old `int 10h/ah=04h` light pen interface which is supported by mouse drivers.  However, the other questions do indeed remain open.